# MYSQL 200 select queries at the same time

Tags: mysql, websocket

At the moment I have a database server in which I have to do about 200 queries with a web socket at the same time (needed for a web socket). At the same time, a process is running 24/7 that adds data to this database.

In addition to this major process, the intention is to send queries to the database regularly to retrieve data from different tables.

The problem:
I feel that Mysql is waiting for the queries. So he runs them alternately while I want them to run asynchronously to keep the speed in. Had already searched somewhere on google about a transaction isolation level but that is not really clear to me ...

I also have the idea that because we run those 200 queries every second he throws me out of the connection. After a while, sometimes half an hour, other times 5 minutes, I get the error messages:

`Database Error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` & `Host '**. ***. **. **' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' "`. Now the latter is easily solved by doing `FLUSH HOSTS` in the mysql terminal but this doesn't seem to be the right solution.

So my question is now, does the error message I get have anything to do with those queries waiting for the 'queue' to get too long? Or is there something else going on?

Information about the database:

- Server type: Mysql
- Runs on Ubuntu

(If more info is needed I will add it later)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will run queries in parallel to the best of its ability without any special intervention.

The message about being blocked is because your web socket is generating so many connection errors in a short timeframe that MySQL is interpreting it as an attack.  You should be monitoring the error feedback being received by your process and resolving whatever issues are occurring.  (It's very likely you will need to raise the server's [max_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections).)

Comment: I have set the limit higher but this also has no effect. Maybe it's because my web socket is making a pool connection to the database?